# Wiping ears in wudu

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, wudu

Is wiping of the ears in wudu sunnah if I don't do it will my wudu be valid what do the scholars say about not wiping the ears

Comment: If it is sunnah then not doing it doesn't invalidate your wudu'.

Answer (score 1):

[The majority are of the view that wiping the ears is Sunnah and mustahabb, but is not obligatory.](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/115246)

Based on that, if a person forgets to wipe his ears, he is fine and his wudoo’ is valid.

And Allah knows best.